# How to map an array object with key from different array set in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a small application in `VueJS` where I'm getting a response in following format:

```
"meeting_summaries":[
    {
        "interaction_id":22,
        "nature":"1",
        "client_name":"Test Company 4",
    },
    {
        "interaction_id":22,
        "nature":"2",
        "client_name":"Test Company 5",
    }
]
```

And I'm having a data set of nature as:

```
const nature = [
    {value: 1, label: "Demo 1"},
    {value: 2, label: "Demo 2"},
    {value: 3, label: "Demo 3"}
]
```

I want to map my `meeting_summaries` with this data set were in `meeting_summaries -> nature` points to `nature -> value` so that my final output can look something like this:

```
"meeting_summaries":[
    {
        "interaction_id":22,
        "nature":"1",
        'nature_name": "Demo 1",
        "client_name":"Test Company 4",
    },
    {
        "interaction_id":22,
        "nature":"2",
        'nature_name": "Demo 2",
        "client_name":"Test Company 5",
    }
]
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with only 2 or 3 attributes plus the code you tried. Use the `<>` snippet editor. We do not need to read through 13 attributes and try to figure out what you added and what you did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `map` through array an add your property using `Object.assing` and `Array.prototype.find`:

```js
const a = {
 "meeting_summaries":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "company_id":7,
        "interaction_id":22,
        "nature":"1",
        "user_id":1,
        "action":"Action Test 1",
        "feedback":"Comment Test 1",
        "created_at":"2017-06-04 10:15:02",
        "updated_at":"2017-06-04 10:15:02",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "client_name":"Test Company 4",
        "mention_name":"Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "company_id":8,
        "interaction_id":22,
        "nature":"2",
        "user_id":1,
        "action":"Action Test 2",
        "feedback":"Comment Test 2",
        "created_at":"2017-06-04 10:15:02",
        "updated_at":"2017-06-04 10:15:02",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "client_name":"Test Company 5","mention_name":"Analyst"
    }
  ]
};

const nature = [
    {value: 1, label: "Demo 1"},
    {value: 2, label: "Demo 2"},
    {value: 3, label: "Demo 3"},
    {value: 4, label: "Demo 4"},
    {value: 5, label: "Demo 5"}
]

const res = a.meeting_summaries.map(ms => Object.assign(ms, 
  (nature.find(n => n.value == ms.nature)) // if corresponding object exists
    ? { nature_name: nature.find(n => n.value == ms.nature).label } : {}
))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hash table and then iterate the `meeting_summaries`.

```js
const object = { meeting_summaries: [{ interaction_id: 22, nature: "1", client_name: "Test Company 4" }, { interaction_id: 22, nature: "2", client_name: "Test Company 5", mention_name: "Analyst" }] },
      nature = [{ value: 1, label: "Demo 1" }, { value: 2, label: "Demo 2" }, { value: 3, label: "Demo 3" }],
      natureMap = Object.assign(...nature.map(o => ({ [o.value]: o.label })));
  
object.meeting_summaries.forEach(o => o.nature_name = natureMap[o.nature]);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and add the `nature_name` property of the found element `label`:

```js
const nature = [{value: 1, label: "Demo 1"},{value: 2, label: "Demo 2"},{value: 3, label: "Demo 3"}];
const obj = {meeting_summaries: [{"interaction_id":22,"nature":"1","client_name":"Test Company 4",},{"interaction_id":22,"nature":"2","client_name":"Test Company 5"}]};

obj.meeting_summaries.forEach(el => el.nature_name = nature.find(n => n.value == el.nature).label);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide full context, but let's assume that "meeting_summaries" is variable:

```js
var meeting_summaries = [{
    "interaction_id": 22,
    "nature": "1",
    "client_name": "Test Company 4",
  },
  {
    "interaction_id": 22,
    "nature": "2",
    "client_name": "Test Company 5",
    "mention_name": "Analyst"
  }
]

const nature = [
  { value: 1, label: "Demo 1" },
  { value: 2, label: "Demo 2" },
  { value: 3, label: "Demo 3" }
]

var meeting_summaries = meeting_summaries.map(ms => {
  ms.nature_name = nature.find(n => ms.nature == n.value).label;
  return ms
})
console.log(meeting_summaries)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just take a "map" approach in my solution for better performance:

```
const meeting_summaries = [ { "interaction_id":22, "nature":"1", "client_name":"Test Company 4", }, { "interaction_id":22, "nature":"2", "client_name":"Test Company 5", } ];

    const nature = [ {value: 1, label: "Demo 1"}, {value: 2, label: "Demo 2"}, {value: 3, label: "Demo 3"} ];

    const natureMap = nature.reduce((accum,current)=>{
                accum[current.value] = current.label;
                return accum;
    }, { });

    const result = meeting_summaries.map(item => {
            item.nature_name = natureMap[item.nature];
            return item;
    });

    console.log(result)
```

Sorry for indentation, coded from smartphone

Answer (score 0):

```js
const baseObj = {
    "meeting_summaries": [
        {
            "interaction_id": 22,
            "nature": "1",
            "client_name": "Test Company 4",
        },
        {
            "interaction_id": 22,
            "nature": "2",
            "client_name": "Test Company 5",
        }
    ]
}

const natures = [
    {value: 1, label: "Demo 1"},
    {value: 2, label: "Demo 2"}
]

 
const meeting_summaries = baseObj.meeting_summaries

natures.forEach((nature, index) => {
    meeting_summaries[index]["nature_name"] = nature.label
})

console.log(baseObj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```